# Con este codigo se corren los campos ¿que puede estar fallando? no son todos los campos pero si algunos salen corridos de la base de datos

Tags: php

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "pcomp"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "base";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "tabla"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "CFN";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";

$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result))
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
       // $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\n";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\r";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con corridos?

Comment: que la informacion sale corrida por el ejemplo lo que debe salir en campo nombre se corre al campo apellido y ahi se corre todos los demas campos¿se entiende?